# I installed flask on my laptop. But it seems to be running only for python3. How to make it work for python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My system has python3 as the default for python command.
when I try to import flask on python command line I get this:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask
>>>
```

but in python3 i get this:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>>
```

How do i correct this?

Comment: Why do you want to use python 2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using two different packaging systems: pip and conda. For Python2, try `pip2 install flask`.